# dev.mysql.com has 2 different installers to download, which do I need?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

If you go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/ there are 2 installers you can download. They both are named exactly the same and have the same version number. There is nothing on the download page to indicate how the 2 versions are different. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up.

"Choosing the right file:

- If you have an online connection while running the MySQL Installer, choose the mysql-installer-web-community file.
- If you do NOT have an online connection while running the MySQL Installer, choose the mysql-installer-community file."